# Openshift/Kubernetes - oc patch all elements of array

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, patch

I'm trying to convert an openshift service from `LoadBalancer` to `ClusterIP` using the `oc patch` command, which requires removing a few elements:

```
oc -n default patch svc router --type json -p '[\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/externalIPs" },\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/0/nodePort" },\
{ "op" : "replace", "path" : "/spec/type", "value" : "ClusterIP" }]'
```

This works fine for services with a single `.spec.ports` entry, however when there are multiple, this fails to remove them all, and the patch operation fails.

Specifically, it fails in this part `"op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/0/nodePort"` since I'm only specifying index 0.

**What would be the proper syntax to patch all elements of the `.spec.ports` array?**

What kind of path language is this? It seems related to `yamlpath` but it only accepts a limited form of forward slash notation.

I've tried multiple variants, which always ends with an error message like `Error from server: jsonpatch remove operation does not apply: doc is missing path: /spec/ports/*/nodePort`.

One possible solution would be to explicitly remove each array index, up to some sufficiently high value, but that's awful.

```
oc -n default patch svc router --type json -p '[\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/externalIPs" },\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/0/nodePort" },\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/1/nodePort" },\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/2/nodePort" },\
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/3/nodePort" },\
...
{ "op" : "remove", "path" : "/spec/ports/99/nodePort" },\
{ "op" : "replace", "path" : "/spec/type", "value" : "ClusterIP" }]'
```

Sample service YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    prometheus.openshift.io/password: OhsPYf5Ae3
    prometheus.openshift.io/username: admin
    service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-generation-error: secret/router-certs
      references serviceUID , which does not match 9ce61b57-9f35-11e9-af68-0050569ec26d
    service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-generation-error-num: "10"
    service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: router-certs
  creationTimestamp: 2019-07-05T15:00:22Z
  labels:
    bah: bah
    router: router
  name: router
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "56450329"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/router
  uid: 9ce61b57-9f35-11e9-af68-0050569ec26d
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.31.122.90
  externalIPs:
  - 10.66.11.44
  - 10.66.11.41
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: 80-tcp
    nodePort: 31380
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: 443-tcp
    nodePort: 30816
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: 1936-tcp
    nodePort: 32677
    port: 1936
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1936
  selector:
    router: router
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.66.11.41
```